# Add Tag or Label to Plotted Line

Tags: pine-script

I will like to add an identifying label or tag to lines that I'm plotting on the charts. Just a simple text line that says "Yesterday's High" or "Yesterday's Low" for example.

I tried using "plotchar" but that didn't quite work. The text was overlapping and repeating over each candle instead of on the plotted line.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
//Values
DH = security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
DL = security(tickerid, 'D', low[1])
WH = security(tickerid, 'W', high[1]) 
WL = security(tickerid, 'W', low[1])

//Plot on charts
plot(isintraday ? DH : na, title = "Day's High", style = line, color = #00BFFF,linewidth = 1, transp = 50) 
plot(isintraday ? DL : na, title = "Day's Low", style = line, color = #00BFFF,linewidth = 1, transp = 50)
plot((isintraday  or isdaily) ? WH : na, title = "Week's High", style = line, color = #007FFF,linewidth = 1, transp = 50) 
plot((isintraday  or isdaily) ? WL : na, title = "Week's Low", style = line, color = #007FFF,linewidth = 1, transp = 50)
```

If possible, I'd prefer that the text not repeat itself everyday.

Also, is it possible to add the day of the week text on top of the Yesterday's High line? I was having difficulty achieving this as well.

Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Look at `Labe`l in the pine documentation. Think it'll helpful in your case. For different text every - you may use `tostring` function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the plotshape() and make use of its "show_last" property like this:

```
plotshape(close, style=shape.labelup, text="close", show_last=1)
```